# Why apply can't be used inside the jQuery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

My sample JSON and js:

```
function foo1(a) { return a*1.5;} //NOTE: foo1 accept one parameter
function foo2(a,b) { return a*1.5 + b;} //NOTE: foo2 accept two parameter
var arr=[ {func:foo1, para:[10]}, {func:foo2, para:[10,20]} ];
```

My jQuery template(Not working):

```
<script id="template1" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        ${$item.data.func.apply(this,$item.data.para)}
</script>
```

Invoking template:

```
 $('#template1').tmpl(arr).appendTo('#mycontainer');
```

My Problem:

- I have different functions which accepts different numbers of parameter (I can't change the # of parameters of the functions)
- So I want to pass the function name in 'func' and parameter in 'para'(as an array) and use "apply" method to invoke the method from inside the jQuery template
- But if I used apply after function (like **$item.data.func.apply**) it throws 'undefined' error

More observation (working):

- If I invoked the method like $item.data.func(10) or $item.data.func(10,20) it works
- At the point where I want to invoke the method `typeof $item.data.func` returns 'function'

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be jQuery Template framework itself use apply to invoke if the expression is of type function. This make things prevent to use **apply** in jQuery template to invoke method.

So here is my trick by introducing a common generic method invoker like

Template:

```
<script id="template1" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    ${genericTrigger($item.data.func, $item.data.para)}
</script>
```

JS:

```
function genericTrigger(func, para) {
    // This need to check, as some unexpected call is coming to this 
    // without passing value
    if (typeof func != 'undefined' && typeof func == 'function') 
    {
       return func.apply(this, para);
    }
}


var arr=[ {func:foo1, para:[10]}, {func:foo2, para:[10,20]} ];
$('#template1').tmpl(arr).appendTo('#mycontainer');
```